# Lubuntu 18.10 QTerminal Window Transparency Setting?

Tags: lubuntu

Default terminal in Lubuntu 18.10 is QTerminal. Somehow, I couldn't find any setting for transparency anywhere.

I found almost similar question here. [Lubuntu terminal background tranparency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1068221/lubuntu-terminal-background-tranparency)

Unfortunately, that's meant for LXterminal in Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS.

Would it be possible to do that in Lubuntu 18.10's QTerminal? If yes, please let me know how.

If not, what is the alternative?

**UPDATE**

Found the setting as advised by DK Bose, but it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: I've edited the answer to mention the need for compositing and how to have Compton run via Autostart. Do let me know if your experience is different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's there in File > Preferences:

[image: QTerminal Transparency settings]

And here's how it looks with 20%:

[image: Example of QTerminal transparency]

---

### Edit:

- I should have mentioned that compositing needs to be turned **on** for transparency effects to work. LXQt uses *Compton* because *Openbox*, the current window manager for Lubuntu 18.10, does not provide compositing by itself
- To enable compositing automatically to survive a reboot or log out, click on *Menu icon > Preferences > LXQt settings > Session Settings > Autostart > Add*.
- In *Name*, enter *Compton*
- For the command, click in the blank box and then on *Search*. You'll be presented with a window showing items in */usr/bin* where you need to scroll down to *compton*, highlight it, click *Open*, and then *OK*. Ensure that the check box next to *Compton* is filled.
- Log out and log back in.

QTerminal should now show the desired transparency.

### Editing your Compton preferences

- You may notice that some of the "default" effects don't suit you.
- To change them to what you like, click on *Menu > Preferences > LXQt settings > Window Effects*.
- Make the changes you want in the GUI window that opens up.
- I suggest **not** making changes in the *Other* tab unless you know what you're doing.
- The changes you make are written to *~/.config/compton.conf* So you need to log out and log back in for the changes to take effect or kill and restart Compton.

Comment: Thanks @DK, I tried that, didn't work. I've shared the screenshot on my updated question.

Comment: Got it. Need to start Compton first at LXQt System Settings > Session Settings > Compton > Start it.

It's not turn on by default.